# Ionic 3 running in the browser: application navigates to root when switch back to Safari

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have built an Ionic 3 app which will be served in the browser (as a PWA).

I build it using *ionic cordova build browser --prod*, everything works as expected, but in iOS's Safari there is a strange behaviour: the app navigates between pages using the NavController's push method and the url changes, using a hash strategy, and when the user go to another app and then returns to iOS, the location from my Ionic app "reset" and the user is sent to to root.

Anyone has any idea of why this can be happening? This does not happen in Android's Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experience is a known 'bug'

Maximiliano Flirtman expose that behavior for ios PWA with:

> Your PWA won’t keep state between sessions, if the user gets out of a PWA, it will be restarted when coming back, so if you need the user to validate an email, SMS or do a two-factor authentication, have that in mind to offer a proper solution.

[See all Maximiliano Flirtman post](https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7).